# jQuery add class to nearest element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried with `.next()`, `.closest()` `.parent()` but non of them worked.

Here is my html markup:

```
<div id="arrownav1" class="ct_as_arrow_nav ">
    <div class="ct_amy_arrows_next">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right next-arrow"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="ct_amy_arrows_prev">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left prev-arrow"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to show left arrow after user does the first click on the right arrow.

I hide it with:

```
jQuery('.ct_amy_arrows_prev').removeClass("prev_show");
```

Then I show it with:

```
jQuery('.ct_amy_arrows_prev').addClass("prev_show");
```

It works but since there are multiple instances of that slider on a page click on the first slider activates all left arrows on all sliders.

So I need a way to just activate that closest element and add prev_show class to it.
What am I doing wrong?

The whole nav code:

```
//Navigation
//==================================================
function initButtons() {
  jQuery('#arrownav' + sliderID + ' .next-arrow').click(function() {
    gonext();
  });
  jQuery('#arrownav' + sliderID + ' .prev-arrow').click(function() {
    goprev();
  });
}
var stopnextslide = 0;

function gonext() {
  var stopnextslide = 0;
  var n = jQuery('#ct_as_amy_sliderid' + sliderID + ' ct_amy_section').length;

  jQuery('#ct_as_amy_sliderid' + sliderID + ' ct_amy_section').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('bespoke-active') && Number(jQuery(this).attr('rel')) + 3 == n) {
      deck.slide(0);
      stopnextslide = 1;
    }
  });
  if (stopnextslide != 1) {
    jQuery(this).closest(".ct_as_arrow_nav").find(".ct_amy_arrows_prev").addClass("prev_show");
    deck.next();
  }
};

function goprev() {
  var stopnextslide = 0;

  var n = jQuery('#ct_as_amy_sliderid' + sliderID + ' ct_amy_section').length;

  jQuery('#ct_as_amy_sliderid' + sliderID + ' ct_amy_section').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('bespoke-active') && Number(jQuery(this).attr('rel')) == 3) {

      deck.slide(n - 1);
      stopnextslide = 1;
    }
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('bespoke-active') && Number(jQuery(this).attr('rel')) == 1) {

    }
  });
  if (stopnextslide != 1) {
    deck.prev();
  }
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Which element you click on?

Comment: I click on .next-arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know the structure. Just navigate up to the parent then search for the previous button. No need to use expensive operations like `closest`

```js
$('.ct_amy_arrows_next').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.ct_amy_arrows_prev').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="arrownav1" class="ct_as_arrow_nav ">
    <div class="ct_amy_arrows_next">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right next-arrow">&gt;</i>
    </div>
    <div class="ct_amy_arrows_prev" style="display: none;">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left prev-arrow">&lt;</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have reworked my solution and used show hide instead of adding classes. Worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `closest` and `find` methods:

```
$('.next-row').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.ct_as_arrow_nav').find('.ct_amy_arrows_prev').addClass("prev_show");
});
```

```js
$('.next-arrow').click(function(){  
 $(this).closest('.ct_as_arrow_nav').find('.ct_amy_arrows_prev').addClass("prev_show");
});
```

```css
.prev_show{
   color:red;
}
i{
   font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="arrownav1" class="ct_as_arrow_nav ">
    <div class="ct_amy_arrows_next">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right next-arrow"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="ct_amy_arrows_prev">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left prev-arrow"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="arrownav2" class="ct_as_arrow_nav ">
    <div class="ct_amy_arrows_next">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right next-arrow"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="ct_amy_arrows_prev">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left prev-arrow"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$(this).closest(".ct_as_arrow_nav")
       .find(".ct_amy_arrows_prev")
       .removeClass("prev_show");;
```

Or like this:

```
$(this).parent()
       .next(".ct_amy_arrows_prev")
       .removeClass("prev_show");
```

**Note:** If the navs are dynamically created then consider binding the events like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)!

**Edit:**

Change your `initButtons` to this:

```
function initButtons() {
  jQuery('#arrownav' + sliderID + ' .next-arrow').click(gonext);
  jQuery('#arrownav' + sliderID + ' .prev-arrow').click(goprev);
}
```

So that `gonewt` and `goprev` will have `this` bound to the arrow buttons.

Comment: This is not working, no class is being added. Any ideas why? Also I had to change $ to jQuery

Comment: @MarcSommerson is the navs dynamically created? Put an alert inside the event listener, does it pop up?

Comment: @MarcSommerson, my answer it is not working for you ? I added a live code snippet.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I guess the navs are dynamically generated and an **event delegation** is required!

Comment: I dont't have any idea.If you look at his post you can see that the click event it is working.

Comment: I have added the whole nav code from js file, please take a look.

Comment: @MarcSommerson, i suggest you to pass as parameter the icon clicked object, because in your current code you have `jQuery(this).closest(".ct_as_arrow_nav").find(".ct_amy_arrows_prev").addClass("prev_show");`  and `this` refers to `window` object, not to your `icon` clicked.